# How to track and load a specific user's information?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, enterprise-portal

I'm making a small portal in ASP.net (with C#.net4) where users can login and add, edit their personal information (PI). But I don't get how to load information (stored in a SQL server DB) in the page when a specific user is logged in.

For example: If Sam is logged in, he can view his PI. When Vicky is logged in, she can view her PI.

who can help me with this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the ID of the logged in user in a [session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) and then use it to filter the query with which you fetch each user's info.

So if a user's ID is 278 then your query would run as:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, * FROM user_table WHERE user_id = 278
```

From a session variable stored like:

```
Session["UserId"] = currentUserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ASP.NET membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) has already taken care of this for you.  Have you considered using it?  You can manage all of your authentication, permissions, roles, and access/edit profile information -- which you define.  You access the data via the membership objects, and you won't need to write a single line of SQL to do it.  It will save you loads of work instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Normally I would recommend this approach as well but Thomas is asking how to track the current user so that his/her individual info can be displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular membership as described in the other answers. Then leverage the Profile system so that each user can view/edit their info when logged in (per the question). CAVEAT: ASP.NET profile system only works out of the box with the Website project template. If you want to use the Web Application project template, then follow the steps here:

[ASP.NET: Web Site versus Web Application Project](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/01/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx)

When you have the profiles up and running, the profile data can be stored in session objects while the user is logged in.